Evaluating limits with as little algebra as possible
I have a solution for this problem, but I'm unsure of

the validity of it and
the efficiency of it.

Problem:
(a) Show that
$$
\frac{1}{n+1} \leq \sum_{r=1}^{n} \frac{1}{n^2+r} \leq \frac{1}{n}
$$
What happens as $n \to \infty$?
(b) Show that
$$
\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+1}} \leq \sum_{r=1}^{n} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2 + r}} \leq \frac{n}{\sqrt{n^2 + 1}}
$$
(c) Find $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{r=1}^{n} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2 + r}}$
And similarly, find $\lim_{n \to \infty} (n!)^{\frac{2}{n}}$.
I did (a) by using induction, but it was a messy algebra: moreover, since these sums generally seem to resemble Riemmann sums I was wondering if there was a potentially cleaner way to do it by using them. Furthermore I solved the limit by observing that, since the sun is bounded between to functions which approach 0, it must also approach 0. For (b) I tried to find a way to use the first part but I couldn't see it. For (c), by using the idea in (a) and the bounds we see it approaches 1, while  for the final limit I notedd that $(\frac{n}{2})^n \leq (n!)^{\frac{2}{n}}$ and since $(\frac{n}{2})^n$ goes to infinity so should that expression.

For you algebra means computation?

Probably should have specified, I'm fine with the general algebra and if introducing a riemman sum makes it too complicated then fine. But I'm quite sure there has to be some way to link a to be so you only need to do one inductive proof. DK tho

I suggest including explicitly what you tried for a) in your post.  For a,b), an easy way (at least for me) is to compare all the terms in the sum with the smallest/biggest term.

Acc nvm I figured out how to do it for a im struggling a bit with b but I like this method a lot  thx

Hint: $\dfrac{1}{n^2+r} \le \dfrac{1}{n^2}$ for all $1 \le r \le n$. Using this gives the right inequality in a). I think this also works for other inequalities in a,b).

Please restrict yourself to one specific problem per post. This way we can help you better.
